# iOS-style "mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" class for Android WebView?

Tags: video, autoplay

There is a class in iOS named "mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" through you can enable/disable the need for user action (touch) to play a video clip. With this set to "NO" (mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction NO), video clips can be auto played inside UIWebView.

I need this in WebView for Android. Is there a similar class, method or property on Android to achieve the same thing?

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

[setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture%28boolean%29) for android 17+?